# Cookie Too Large Error even with hight large_client_header_buffers

Tags: nginx, cookies, 400-bad-request

I have multiple instances of my web application on different subdomains, which act as different regions of our product.

The problem is that I save my authentication information on cookie in a domain level and because token size are large I get the following error in Nginx.

```
400 Bad Request
Request Header Or Cookie Too Large
nginx/1.25.2
```

I have increased the size of large_client_header_buffers twice but it doesn't work anymore. and The weird part is that I get that error for different number of cookies for every region. For example, our QA server shows the error after 20 cookies are set, but our US region start showing it after 8 cookies are set, event hough the Ngnix conf is the same for all of them.

That's why I'm wondering if there's any other place where I need to config large_client_header_buffers that I don't know of.
(we're using docker-compose on EC2).